# How to install gdb with no package manager?

Tags: linux, command-line, gdb

I'm trying to reverse engineer some software on a system that runs embedded Linux. I've ssh-ed into it, and right now I'm trying to attach gdb to one of the processes so I can get some information on it. However, gdb is not installed on this system. That wouldn't normally be a problem, except there's also no package manager. Not only that, there's no wget, curl, git, make, or dpkg. I can put files onto the system with scp, but without make I'm not sure how to install them. What would my best course of action be here?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `gdbserver` in such circumstances. It’s a small binary, which can easily be cross-compiled for your target platform. Copy it there, and then you’ll be able to use it to connect a `gdb` running on another system to your embedded system.

See [the `gdbserver` chapter in the GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html#Server) for details.